# How to update node modules programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to use the `npm` update from a script. Below is my code:

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load(function () {
npm.commands.outdated({json: true}, function (err, data) {
    //console.log(data);
    npm.commands.update(function(err, d){
        console.log(d);
    });
   });
});
```

When I run this script, the modules get updated, but the new versions are not indicated in the package.json.

When I run `npm update --save-dev`  from command line, folders and package.json get updated.

Please suggest how this can be achieved through the script.
How can I use `--save-dev` option through code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify the `{save: true}` option when loading the config:

```
npm.load({save: true}, function() {
  // update code
});
```

**Edit:**

The `'save-dev'` option for the `npm.load` command does not work. There's an issue about it here: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2369.

The work around is to re-install outdated modules:

```
npm.load({'save-dev': true}, function () {
  npm.commands.outdated(function (err, rawOutdated) {
    var outdated = rawOutdated.map(function (module) {
      return module[1];
    });
    npm.commands.install(outdated, function(err, d) {

    });
   });
});
```

Comment: It works!! but it does not do anything with the devdependencies...I tried using    {save: true, dev: true} / {'--save-dev' : true} / {save-dev:true}...none of them work.....Is there a way to update dev dependencies

Comment: I've confirmed `save-dev: true` does not work. A work around would be to use `npm install` instead of `npm update`.

Comment: The work around is to re-install outdated modules:  --> updated the dev dependencies in package.json

Answer (score 2):

I think the first argument in the `npm.commands.update` is a list of arguments. I have never used npm programmatically, but looking at their source code I would try the following:

```
npm.commands.update(['--save-dev'], function(err, d){
    console.log(d);
});
```

The reference is on this test: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/test/tap/update-save.js#L87

Comment: Did you have a look at the link I pasted? That might help to discover how to use it.

Comment: @Krishnaveni: Can you try `{ saveDev : true }` instead of `['--save-dev']` ?

Comment: { saveDev : true } -- undefined.                                                                              I tried {save:true, dev: true} -- this does not give err, but it does not change the package.json